# Javascript date query on PostgreSQL Database always returns null

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL Database set up and i have the following table

```sql
create table LOR
(
    PLR_ID         int primary key,
    visibility     int,
    planning_space text,
    tessellate     int,
    extrude        int,
    size_m2        real,
    stand          date,
    area_key       int references Bezirkgrenzen (area_key)
);
```

When i try to retrive data from the database from javascript everything gets retrived apart from the date, that always comes up as `null`

```js
var pg = require('pg');

var connectionString = {
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'test',
    password: '123',
    port: 5432,
};

var pool = new pg.Pool(connectionString);

pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {

    const query = client.query(new pg.Query("select * from lor"))
    query.on('row', (row) => {
        console.log(row);
    })
    query.on('end', (res) => {
        // pool shutdown
        console.log("ending");
        pool.end()
    })
    query.on('error', (res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })

    done()
})
```

Result:

```
{
  plr_id: 11300616,
  visibility: -1,
  planning_space: 'HohenschÃ¶nhausener StraÃŸe',
  tessellate: -1,
  extrude: 0,
  size_m2: 416963.7,
  stand: null,
  area_key: 11
}
ending
```

and here is the entry in the database
[image]

Comment: Not sure, but wondering if you need to do something with types https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types to convert the PG date type into a string/JS date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So adding these two lines at the start helps fix the problem

```js
var types = require('pg').types
types.setTypeParser(types.builtins.DATE, (val) => val === null ? null : val);
```

```
{
  plr_id: 11300616,
  visibility: -1,
  planning_space: 'HohenschÃ¶nhausener StraÃŸe',
  tessellate: -1,
  extrude: 0,
  size_m2: 416963.7,
  stand: '01.01.2021',
  area_key: 11
}
ending
```